# Toggling a class fails in a ajax table

Tags: jquery

I have this html table

```
<table id="search" class="order-table table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Group Title</th>
          <th>Group Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="in_modal">

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

which i am getting the rows from the server with

```
    var baseurl = "<?php print base_url('index.php/enterprise/get_all_groups'); ?>";
    $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: baseurl,
  success: function(data){
     $('#in_modal').html(data);
  }
    });
```

and then using

```
$( "tr" ).on( "click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings().removeClass("selected");
    });
```

to toggle the class `selected` on click.What i want is when i clcik a row,that table is given the class `selected` and the class is removed from the old row and given to the new clicked row when i click on another row.

When i try clicking any row,this does not highlight any row.How can i highlight a row on click?.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $( "tr" ).on( "click", function() {
    $("tr").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```